# Array of pointers to nodes not declared in scope

Tags: c++, arrays, scope

I'm trying to assign a node to a pointer along an array of pointers but it keeps telling me that my array was not declared in the scope. I'm totally confused on how or why so any help would be greatly beneficial! Thanks for taking the time to respond!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "book.h"

using namespace std;

class bookstore
{

private:

    int amount = 5;
    int counting = 0;
public:

    bookstore()

    {

        bookstore *store;
        store = new book*[amount];
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            store[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    ~bookstore(){ delete[] store; }
    void addbook(string a,string b, string c, string d, string e)
    {
        if (counting == amount)
        {
            cout<<"Full House!"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        store[counting] = new book(a,b,c,d,e);
        counting++;
    }
    void print()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            cout<<store[i]->name<<" "<<store[i]->publisher<<" "<<store[i]->year<<" "<<store[i]->price<<" "<<store[i]->category<<endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: In C++ if you declare a variable in a function inside curly braces `{ ..... }`, it no longer exists after the `}` .

Answer (score 2):

Your pointer `store` is local to the default constructor. It looks like you're after a data member. Furthermore, you seem to be after an array of pointers. If so, you need `bookstore` needs to be a pointer to pointer:

```
class bookstore
{
private:

    bookstore** store; // or bookstore* store 
    int amount = 5;
    int counting = 0;
```

and fix the constructor to use that:

```
bookstore()
{
    store = new book*[amount]; // or store = new book[amount]
    ....
```

Note that your class is attempting to manage dynamically allocated resources, so you will need to take care of the copy constructor and assignment operators (either make the class non-copyable and non-assignable, or implement them. The defaults are not acceptable. See [*the rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).) If you are really using an array of dynamically allocated pointers, then you need to fix your destructor too. Currently, it only deletes the array, but not the objects pointed at by the pointers in it.

The better solution would be to use a class that manages the resources for you and has the desired semantics. It is easier to have each class handle a single responsibility.

Comment: @user3553272 Glad it helped. You can select this answer (unless you want to wait for possible other answers first), it will even get you some rep points. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information.